# How to compute the Moment Generating Function of R.V.'s $X_1 - X_2$

Tags: probability, transformation, moment-generating-functions

I want to show that 
$$Y_1 + Y_2 \overset{d}= X_1 - X_2$$
where $Y_1, Y_2 \sim \text{Laplace}(1)$ and $X_1,X_2 \sim \Gamma(2,1)$, by checking their Moment Generating Functions.

For the left-hand side, since $Y_1, Y_2$ are iid, I use the fact that $S_{n=2}=Y_1+Y_2$, and that 
$$\psi_{S_{n=2}}(s)=(\psi_Y(t))^{n=2}=\left(\frac 1 {1+a^2t^2}\right)^{n=2}=\left[L(a=1)\right]=\left(\frac 1 {1+t^2}\right)^{2}$$
However I am not sure how to solve the right hand side, i.e. $X_1 - X_2$,  nor how to find its MGF. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean with $Y_1,Y_2 \in L(1)$. And $X_1, X_2 \in Γ(2,1)$?

Comment: That $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are Laplace-distributed R.V.'s and that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are Gamma-dristributed R.V.'s

Comment: If you want to find the density, you convolve the pdf's if adding independent random variables with densities $f,g$, i.e. the density is $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(t)g(x-t) dt$. The PDF of $-X$ with $X$ having pdf $f(x)$ is just $f(-x)$. But this isn't a great approach.

Comment: @Batman, Thanks for the answers, Im currently trying to figuring it all out. Why is convolution not a good approach and why is $E[e^{t (X_1 - X_2)}] = E[e^{t X_1} e^{-t X_2}]$ better?

Comment: Because its faster, and your less likely to make an integration error since you're not computing a convolution integral then trying to do the transformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Laplacian distribution with parameter $\gamma$ can be written as $\gamma (E_1 - E_2)$ where $E_1, E_2$ are independent standard exponential random variables. This is easy to show by matching their MGF's, or by directly computation.

Thus, the left hand side is $E_1 - E_2 + E_3 -E_4$ where $E_1, E_2, E_3, E_4$ are i.i.d. Exp(1) random variables. Lump $E_1+ E_3$ together (this is $X_1$) and $E_2 + E_4$ together (this is $X_2$) to get the result.

Alternatively, you can note that the MGF of the right hand side (with $X_1, X_2$ independent) is given by $E[e^{t (X_1 - X_2)}] = E[e^{t X_1} e^{-t X_2}] = M_{X_1}(t) M_{X_2}(-t)$ and write this out by plugging in the MGF of a $\Gamma(2,1)$ distribution, and see that this matches the MGF of the LHS.

Comment: I can't get it to fit since my LHS = $\frac 1 {(1+t^2)^2}$ = $\frac 1 {1+2t²+t⁴}$, while my RHS = $\frac 1 {(1-t)²} * \frac 1 {(1+t)²}$ = $\frac 1 {1-2t²+t⁴}$. I.e. a positive vs. a negative 2 on respective side. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The Laplacian MGF will be $1/(1-t^2)$ not $1/(1+t^2$).

Comment: The hero I need, thanks! I was using the characteristic function without the imaginary part.